# dynamically allocated string arrays failed to be deallocated

Tags: c++

I have the following piece of code:

```
string * p = new string[8];
cout<<sizeof(p)<<endl;
free(p);
```

which seems ok to me but failed with:

```
8
a.out(85837) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fb5b3403ae8: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Another test on an integer array worked. Is there anything special with c++ string?

Comment: Not reading through the entire chapter in that guide? Not good.

Comment: @KerrekSB Bookmarked.

Comment: You spelled `std::vector<string>(8)` wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yap. `new []` pairs with `delete []`. `free()`ing causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Ah, my bad. It seems free pairs with new for the built-in types.

Comment: @HailiangZhang No, it doesn't. `new` pairs with `delete`, `new []` pairs with `delete []` and `malloc()`, `calloc()` and `realloc()` pair with `free()`. Any other combination is erroneous.

Comment: Also, from your code, it seems to me that you are expecting the `sizeof` operator to yield 8. It probably won't (unless you are [un]lucky enough to use a 64-bit system). [This is why.](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html)

Comment: Lol I wanted to make sure mine was higher until he accepted an answer

Answer (score 12):

First of all, when you use `new` you need to use `delete`, not `free()`. In fact, you should really never use `free()` or `malloc()` in C++. A good explanation for why you should never mix `new` and `free` or `malloc()` and delete is that `new` and `delete` call the constructor and destructor, `free()` and `malloc()` have nothing to do with that, they just allocate and deallocate memory, especially for built in classes this is bad because you don't know what is supposed to happen in `std::string`'s destructor or constructor, it might be possible to make it work with your own built in class (but don't do it).

You can replace your code with this:

```
string * p = new string[8];
cout<<sizeof(p)<<endl;
delete [] p;
```

In the end, I would suggest you use a built in data type like `std::vector` or `std::array`. They are much more C++-ish than a standard old C array.