# Why a dynamically allocate object failed to be freed?

Tags: c++

I know it should be a trivial question but need to find out why.

The following code compiled by failed with

```
a.out(93143) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff5af8293f: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

codes:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
};

class B
{
    private:
        A a;
    public:
        B(){a=*new A();}
        ~B(){delete &a;}
};

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

According to the immediate comments, I realized that the dynamically allocated object in "new" immediately lost its owner after assigning to "a". Now if I do want an object instead of a pointer to "A", what is the best solution?

Comment: what you are doing?? `a` is not pointer

Comment: Also you dont know the address to free(). *new A() ----> you did not take this address. Just took the value. :D

Comment: I was deleting &a, right?

Comment: see `sizeof(void*)` may not equal to `sizeof(object)` even `sizeof(int)` for some machinne

Comment: Didn't u just ask a question like this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711483/dynamically-allocated-string-arrays-failed-to-be-deallocated/17711510#17711510)

Comment: You created a copy and lost (leaked) the original.

Comment: You meant I have to declare a pointer to A in class B?

Comment: @Ed S. I see! Only the returning value of "new" has the ownership of the object.

Comment: So, what is the best solution if I do need an object instead of pointer in class B?

Comment: @HailiangZhang if you need an object, use an object. No need to call `new` to dynamically allocate one, or `delete` to free it. As it currently is, every instance of `B` already had an instance of object `A` already!

Comment: `B() :a() {}` is the obvious way

Comment: Good http://sscce.org -- +1

Comment: @HailiangZhang: Kinda.  What's important is the *address*, i.e., the *value* of the pointer returned by `new`.  You can copy that as many times as you like, but the *address* you pass to `delete` (the *value* of the pointer you pass) must be the same as that returned by `new`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because your member variable is not a pointer. You're not storing the dynamically allocated object you're assigning a copy of it to `A a;` and leaking the dynamically allocated one.

Change class B to:

```
class B
{
    private:
        A* a;
    public:
        B(){a= new A();}
        ~B(){delete a;}
};
```

or better yet

```
class B
{
    private:
        A a;
    public:
        B() {}
        ~B(){}
};
```

In case you *really* need a dynamically allocated object, I would like to propose this final solution using smart pointers (you'll need C++11 or boost for this):

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A() { std::cout << "Hi" << std::endl; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "Bye" << std::endl; }
};

class B
{
public:
    B(): a(new A()) {};
    //~B() {} <-- destructor is no longer needed, the unique_ptr will delete the object for us
private:
    std::unique_ptr<A> a;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    B b;
}
```

You can see that the constructor and destructor for A is called [here](http://ideone.com/kckwL4).

Comment: The call to the default constructor in the second example is redundant, but the concept is the correct one +1

Comment: Yup! that is the way you do it :).

Comment: Yes, I think this is a standard C++ way to do it. But what if I do need an object instead of a pointer in "B", and I want to dynamicaly allocate the object?

Comment: @HailiangZhang First and third examples show you what to do if you really need a dynamically allocated object.

Comment: If you need to do dynamic allocation, by that very requirement you use a pointer and not an "object"

Comment: Thanks guys. Just a further question: how popular is the C++11 in the current world?